# Not getting hashmap from bundle - Android

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-intent, android-activity, android-asynctask

I want to get HashMap which is being passed through Bundle from a AsyncTask. But I am getting NullPointerException.

Flow is like below...

```
FragmentMainActivity -> TableScreenSectionwiseActivity -> GetSectionsAsync

HashMap is passed from GetSectionsAsync to TableScreenSectionwiseActivity through Bundle.
```

#### Note: 
FragmentMainActivity is **FragmentActivity**.
TableScreenSectionwiseActivity  is **Fragment**.
GetSectionsAsync is a **AsyncTask**.

What I have tried, is like below.

Error I getting...

[Error Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jI9ac.png)

**TableScreenSectionwiseActivity.java**

```
package com.malaka.ui;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;

import adapters.table_section_adapter;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.animation.Animation;
import android.view.animation.AnimationUtils;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.malaka.R;
import com.malaka.helper.ActionItem;
import com.malaka.helper.GetSectionsGetterSetter;
import com.malaka.helper.Logout;
import com.malaka.helper.PopupWindows;
import com.malaka.helper.QuickAction;
import com.malaka.helper.QuickActionLocation;
import com.malaka.helper.ReplaceFragment;
import com.malaka.helper.async.GetSectionsAsync;
import com.malaka.helper.async.TableStatusAsync;
import com.malaka.utils.PreferenceUtils;

public class TableScreenSectionwiseActivity extends Fragment implements
        OnItemClickListener {

    final static String TAG = "TableScreenSectionwiseActivity";
    private static final int ID_TABLE = 1;
    private static final int ID_TASK = 2;
    private static final int ID_MANAGER = 3;
    private static final int ID_RECIPE = 4;
    private static final int ID_INSTRUCTION = 5;
    private static final int ID_SEARCH = 6;
    private static final int ID_HELP = 7;
    private static final int ID_SETTING = 8;
    private static final int ID_LOGOUT = 9;

    private static final int ID_KP = 10;
    private static final int ID_BANER = 20;
    private static final int ID_CITY = 30;

    String[] values = new String[] { "1", "2" };

    public static FragmentActivity activity;

    RelativeLayout rl;
    static PreferenceUtils pref;
    QuickAction quickAction;
    QuickActionLocation quickActionLocation;
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map1;
    ArrayList<String> ids, names;

    ListView section_list;
    TextView version, malaka;
    ImageView refresh;
    Animation rotation;
    private TextView mDropdownTitle;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
            Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_screen_sectionwise,
                container, false);
        init(view);
        return view;
    }

    private void init(View view) {

        activity = getActivity();
        pref = new PreferenceUtils(getActivity());

        malaka = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.txt_malaka_title_table_sectionwise);
        malaka.setText(pref.getLocation());

        if (!pref.getSectionStatus()) {
            GetSectionsAsync getSectionsAsync = new GetSectionsAsync(
                    getActivity());
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("Location_Name", pref.getLocation());
            getSectionsAsync.execute(map);
        }

        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        Log.e("Bundle Size: ", bundle.size() + "");

        map1 = (HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>>) getArguments()
                .getSerializable("SECTIONS_HASHMAP");
        GetSectionsGetterSetter.setData(map1);
        ids = map1.get("ID_LIST");
        names = map1.get("NAME_LIST");

        for (int i = 0; i < names.size(); i++) {
            Log.e("Names: ", names.get(i));
        }

        section_list = (ListView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.section_name_list_view);
        table_section_adapter adapter = new table_section_adapter(
                activity.getApplicationContext(), values);
        section_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        section_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);

        rl = (RelativeLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.ll_location_sectionwise);
        if (pref.getUserRole()) {
            rl.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        } else {
            rl.setVisibility(View.GONE);
        }
        rl.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                quickActionLocation.show(arg0);
            }
        });

        version = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.table_version_sectionwise);
        version.setText(pref.getVersion());

        rotation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(getActivity(),
                R.anim.refresh_dialog);
        refresh = (ImageView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.img_refresh_table_sectionwise);
        refresh.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                refresh.startAnimation(rotation);
                TableStatusAsync Async = new TableStatusAsync(getActivity());
                HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
                map.put("UserId", pref.getUserId());
                map.put("SectionId", "0");
                map.put("Location", pref.getLocation());
                Async.execute(map);
            }
        });

        ActionItem tableItem = new ActionItem(ID_TABLE, "Table Status");
        ActionItem taskItem = new ActionItem(ID_TASK, "My Tasks");
        ActionItem managerItem = new ActionItem(ID_MANAGER, "Manager");
        ActionItem recipeItem = new ActionItem(ID_RECIPE, "Recipes");
        ActionItem instItem = new ActionItem(ID_INSTRUCTION, "Instructions");
        ActionItem searchItem = new ActionItem(ID_SEARCH, "Search");
        ActionItem helpItem = new ActionItem(ID_HELP, "Help");
        ActionItem settingItem = new ActionItem(ID_SETTING, "Settings");
        ActionItem logoutItem = new ActionItem(ID_LOGOUT, "Logout");

        ActionItem kpItem = new ActionItem(ID_KP, "Koregaon Park");
        ActionItem cityItem = new ActionItem(ID_CITY, "Phoneix Market");
        ActionItem banerItem = new ActionItem(ID_BANER, "Baner");

        quickActionLocation = new QuickActionLocation(getActivity(),
                QuickActionLocation.VERTICAL);
        quickActionLocation.addActionItem(kpItem, Color.WHITE);
        quickActionLocation.addActionItem(cityItem, Color.WHITE);
        quickActionLocation.addActionItem(banerItem, Color.WHITE);

        // use setSticky(true) to disable QuickAction dialog being dismissed
        // after an item is clicked
        // tableItem.setSticky(true);

        // create QuickAction. Use QuickAction.VERTICAL or
        // QuickAction.HORIZONTAL param to define layout
        // orientation
        quickAction = new QuickAction(getActivity(), QuickAction.VERTICAL);

        // add action items into QuickAction
        quickAction.addActionItem(tableItem, Color.WHITE);
        quickAction.addActionItem(taskItem, Color.parseColor("#F2A523"));
        if (pref.getUserRole()) {
            quickAction.addActionItem(managerItem, Color.parseColor("#F2A523"));
        }
        if (pref.getRecipeScreenStatus()) {
            quickAction.addActionItem(recipeItem, Color.parseColor("#F2A523"));
        }
        quickAction.addActionItem(instItem, Color.parseColor("#F2A523"));
        quickAction.addActionItem(searchItem, Color.parseColor("#F2A523"));
        quickAction.addActionItem(helpItem, Color.parseColor("#F2A523"));
        quickAction.addActionItem(settingItem, Color.parseColor("#F2A523"));
        quickAction.addActionItem(logoutItem, Color.parseColor("#F2A523"));

        // Set listener for action item clicked
        quickAction
                .setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickAction.OnActionItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(QuickAction source, int pos,
                            int actionId) {
                        ActionItem actionItem = quickAction.getActionItem(pos);
                        quickAction.dismiss();
                        // here we can filter which action item was clicked with
                        // pos or actionId parameter
                        if (actionId == ID_TABLE) {
                            closeDropdown();
                        } else if (actionId == ID_TASK) {
                            closeDropdown();
                            ReplaceFragment.getReplaceFragment(getActivity(),
                                    new TaskLeadingActivity(), "left");
                        } else if (actionId == ID_MANAGER) {
                            closeDropdown();
                            ReplaceFragment.getReplaceFragment(getActivity(),
                                    new ManagerPageActivity(), "left");
                        } else if (actionId == ID_RECIPE) {
                            closeDropdown();
                            ReplaceFragment.getReplaceFragment(getActivity(),
                                    new ReceipiesScreenActivity(), "left");
                        } else if (actionId == ID_INSTRUCTION) {
                            closeDropdown();
                            ReplaceFragment.getReplaceFragment(getActivity(),
                                    new InstructionActivity(), "left");
                        } else if (actionId == ID_SEARCH) {
                            closeDropdown();
                        } else if (actionId == ID_HELP) {
                            closeDropdown();
                        } else if (actionId == ID_SETTING) {
                            closeDropdown();
                            ReplaceFragment.getReplaceFragment(getActivity(),
                                    new SettingScreenActivity(), "left");
                        } else if (actionId == ID_LOGOUT) {
                            closeDropdown();
                            Logout logout = new Logout(getActivity());
                        }
                    }
                });

        // set listnener for on dismiss event, this listener will be called only
        // if QuickAction dialog was dismissed
        // by clicking the area outside the dialog.
        quickAction.setOnDismissListener(new QuickAction.OnDismissListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDismiss() {
                // Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Dismissed",
                // Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                closeDropdown();
            }
        });

        // Set listener for action item clicked
        quickActionLocation
                .setOnActionItemClickListener(new QuickActionLocation.OnActionItemClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onItemClick(QuickActionLocation source,
                            int pos, int actionId) {
                        ActionItem actionItem = quickActionLocation
                                .getActionItem(pos);
                        quickActionLocation.dismiss();
                        // here we can filter which action item was clicked with
                        // pos or actionId parameter
                        if (actionId == ID_KP) {
                            getTableStatus("Koregaon Park");
                        } else if (actionId == ID_CITY) {
                            getTableStatus("Phoneix Market City");
                        } else if (actionId == ID_BANER) {
                            getTableStatus("Baner");
                        }
                    }
                });

        mDropdownTitle = ((TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.dropdown_textview_table_sectionwise));
        mDropdownTitle.setText(pref.getUserNameToGetManagerPage()
                .substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()
                + pref.getUserNameToGetManagerPage().substring(1).toLowerCase()
                + "   ");
        final TextView dropDownTextView = (TextView) view
                .findViewById(R.id.dropdown_textview_table_sectionwise);
        dropDownTextView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (PopupWindows.mWindow.isShowing()) {
                    closeDropdown();
                } else {
                    openDropdown();
                }
                quickAction.show(v);
            }
        });
    }

    public void getTableStatus(String location) {
        pref.setLocation(location);
        Log.e(TAG, "location : " + pref.getLocation());
        TableStatusAsync Async = new TableStatusAsync(getActivity());
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        map.put("UserId", pref.getUserId());
        map.put("SectionId", "0");
        map.put("Location", pref.getLocation());
        Async.execute(map);
    }

    private void openDropdown() {
        mDropdownTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,
                R.drawable.arrow_up, 0);
    }

    private void closeDropdown() {
        mDropdownTitle.setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(0, 0,
                R.drawable.arrow_down, 0);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
            long id) {
        Toast.makeText(activity, "Clicked" + position, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)
                .show();
    }
}
```

**GetSectionsAsync.java**

```
package com.malaka.helper.async;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.Map;

import org.ksoap2.SoapEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.PropertyInfo;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapObject;
import org.ksoap2.serialization.SoapSerializationEnvelope;
import org.ksoap2.transport.HttpTransportSE;

import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentActivity;
import android.util.Log;

import com.malaka.helper.AsyncAttributes;
import com.malaka.helper.ReplaceFragment;
import com.malaka.helper.TableStatusXmlParser;
import com.malaka.ui.CustomerDetailsActivity;
import com.malaka.ui.TableScreenSectionwiseActivity;
import com.malaka.utils.CommanUtils;
import com.malaka.utils.NetworkUtils;
import com.malaka.utils.PreferenceUtils;

public class GetSectionsAsync extends
        AsyncTask<Map<String, String>, Void, Void> {

    final static String TAG = "GetSectionsAsync";
    FragmentActivity context;
    String xml;
    HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> details;
    PreferenceUtils pref;
    int response;
    boolean isConnected;

    public GetSectionsAsync(FragmentActivity context) {
        this.context = context;
        pref = new PreferenceUtils(context);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        CommanUtils.getDialogShow(context, "Please Wait...");
    }

    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Map<String, String>... params) {

        if (NetworkUtils.isConnectedToInternet(context)) {
            isConnected = true;
            HashMap<String, String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) params[0];
            SoapObject request = new SoapObject(
                    AsyncAttributes.GetSecNAMESPACE,
                    AsyncAttributes.GetSecMETHOD_NAME);

            Iterator<String> iterator = map.keySet().iterator();

            PropertyInfo pi = new PropertyInfo();
            pi.setName("RLocation");
            pi.setValue(map.get("Location_Name"));
            pi.setType(String.class);
            request.addProperty(pi);

            while (iterator.hasNext()) {
                String key = iterator.next();
                request.addProperty(key, map.get(key));
                Log.e(TAG, "user id key: " + key + " value: " + map.get(key));
            }

            SoapSerializationEnvelope envelope = new SoapSerializationEnvelope(
                    SoapEnvelope.VER11);
            envelope.dotNet = true;
            envelope.setOutputSoapObject(request);
            HttpTransportSE androidHttpTransport = new HttpTransportSE(
                    AsyncAttributes.GetSecURL);

            try {
                androidHttpTransport.call(AsyncAttributes.GetSecSOAP_ACTION,
                        envelope);
                SoapObject result = (SoapObject) envelope.bodyIn;

                if (result
                        .toString()
                        .equals("GetSectionsForLocationResponse{GetSectionsForLocationResult=Failur; }")) {
                    String xmltemp = String.valueOf(result).split("=")[1];
                    xml = xmltemp.split(";")[0];
                } else {
                    String xmltemp = "<NewDataSet>\n"
                            + String.valueOf(result).split("<NewDataSet>")[1];
                    xml = xmltemp.split("</NewDataSet>")[0] + "</NewDataSet>";
                }
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

            if (xml == null) {
                response = 1;
                Log.e(TAG, "xml null");
            } else if (xml.equals("No Table available")) {
                response = 2;
            } else {
                response = 2;
                Log.e(TAG, "Task 1 result " + xml);
                details = TableStatusXmlParser.getSectionsXml(xml, context);
            }
        } else {
            isConnected = false;
        }
        return null;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

        CommanUtils.getDialogDismiss();
        if (!isConnected) {
            CommanUtils.showAlertDialog("Internet Is Required", context);
        } else if (response == 1) {
            CommanUtils.getToast("Server Error", context);
        }
        if (response == 2) {
            pref.setSectionStatus(true);
            goAhead();
        }
    }

    private void goAhead() {
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putSerializable("SECTIONS_HASHMAP", details);
        Fragment fragment = new TableScreenSectionwiseActivity();
        fragment.setArguments(bundle);
        ReplaceFragment.getReplaceFragment(context, fragment, "");
    }
}
```

If you guys want FragmentMainActivity code. I can put it. But I dont think so it is required. Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you have TableScreenSectionwiseActivity in one of your layout?

Comment: remove it from the layout. Use only the runtime transaction

Comment: So, What to write instead. `View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.table_screen_sectionwise,
    container, false);`

Comment: Do you have `<fragment` in your Activity's layout?

Comment: Yes. I have fragment_main_activity.xml which includes `<fragment`.

Comment: replace it with a <FrameLayout. Assign it an id. Use a transaction to add your Fragment to the FrameLayout

Comment: Same error bro.@Blackbelt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I have achieved it through INTERFACE.

Just do like below...

1. Make interface in `GetSectionsAsync.java` named `FragmentInterfaceCallBack` and declare a method named `onTaskCompleted()`.
2. Now define a method in `GetSectionsAsync.java` named `setFragmentInterfaceCallBack` which will set the interface's object while calling from `TableScreenSectionwiseActivity.java`.
3. Now in `onPostExecute` method write below code....`interfaceCallBack.onTaskCompleted(details);` **details** is a data received from web service.
4. Go to `TableScreenSectionwiseActivity.java` and implements `FragmentInterfaceCallBack`, define it's `onTaskCompleted()` method and add below code to `TableScreenSectionwiseActivity.java` where you are calling AsyncTask `getSectionsAsync.setFragmentInterfaceCallBack(this);` where `getSectionsAsync` is a object of `GetSectionsAsync.java`.

In `onTaskCompleted()` method you get your desire data.

**I have made below changes in my both files.**

**GetSectionsAsync.java**

**Making interface and defining `setFragmentInterfaceCallBack()` method....**

`private FragmentInterfaceCallBack interfaceCallBack;`

```
public interface FragmentInterfaceCallBack {
    public void onTaskCompleted(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> map);
}

public void setFragmentInterfaceCallBack(
        FragmentInterfaceCallBack _interfaceCallBack) {
    this.interfaceCallBack = _interfaceCallBack;
}
```

**In onPostExecute method....**

`protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);`

```
    CommanUtils.getDialogDismiss();
    if (!isConnected) {
        CommanUtils.showAlertDialog("Internet Is Required", context);
    } else if (response == 1) {
        CommanUtils.getToast("Server Error", context);
    }
    if (response == 2) {
        pref.setSectionStatus1(true);
        // goAhead();
    }
    interfaceCallBack.onTaskCompleted(details);
}
```

**TableScreenSectionwiseActivity.java**

**Implementing interface....**
`public class TableScreenSectionwiseActivity extends Fragment implements OnItemClickListener, FragmentInterfaceCallBack {`

**Calling AsyncTask....**
`if (!pref.getSectionStatus1()) {
            Log.e("Once Again in TableScreenSectionwiseActivity: ", "hmm....");
            GetSectionsAsync getSectionsAsync = new GetSectionsAsync(
                    getActivity());
            getSectionsAsync.setFragmentInterfaceCallBack(this);
            HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
            map.put("Location_Name", pref.getLocation());
            getSectionsAsync.execute(map);
        }`

**Defining interface's method....**
`@Override
    public void onTaskCompleted(HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> hashMap) {
        ids = hashMap.get("ID_LIST");
        names = hashMap.get("NAME_LIST");
        table_section_adapter adapter = new table_section_adapter(
                activity.getApplicationContext(), names, ids);
        section_list.setAdapter(adapter);
        section_list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }`

That's it. Hope this will help someone..

Answer (score 0):

```
 Map<String, String> map = ((Bundle)appRestrictions.get(key)).keySet().stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x, x -> bundle.get(x).toString()));
            JSONObject jsonNested = new JSONObject(map);
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?